# Podcast software with Cue Sheet support

Tags: mp3, podcasts, cue-sheet

I am looking for an all-in-one solution which can do at least the first 2, preferably all 3 of the following steps from my current manual process:

1. Podcast download (currently using iTunes)
2. Search for and download matching Cue Sheet from web (currently using [CueNation](http://cuenation.com))
3. Use the CUE file to split the MP3 (currently using [Medieval CUE Splitter](http://www.medieval.it/content/view/28/70/))

Does such a thing exist?

Or do I have to break out my C# skills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'll have to code it myself then! =]